# System.StackOverflowException when using switch case in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I m developing a web application in ASP.NET WebForms, in that I'm filling a gridView with 1000's of records and doing some calculation part in OnRowDataBound event. In OnRowDataBound event there is a switch case containing a 100's of switch case and the whole OnRowDataBound event function is something around 13000 lines of codes. Now when I run the application to get data from server without OnRowDataBound event, it fetches all the records containing 1000+ records but when I try to get that records with OnRowDataBound  event containing those 100's of switch cases it goes into System.StackOverFlowException.

As a way around solution I tried to reduce those switch cases to 20, it then run without any error but goes into exception when OnRowDataBound event has 100's of switch cases.

ASPX Page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReport" runat="server" CellPadding="4" Font-Names="calibri(body)"
                                            Font-Size="9" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Vertical"  OnRowDataBound="gvReport_RowDataBound"
                                            ShowFooter="True" OnRowCreated="gvReport_RowCreated" OnPreRender="gvReport_PreRender"
                                            EmptyDataText="No Data Retrieved">
                                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                            </Columns>
                                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="Freezing"
                                                Wrap="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="#505050"
                                                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" />
                                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                                        </asp:GridView>
```

ASPX.cs page

```
protected void gvReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    { 
switch(Condition){
            case"":{
                   try
                {
                    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            strPrevious = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Territory").ToString();

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                        dblSubTotal += Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Retailer code").ToString());
                        dblTotal += Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Retailer code").ToString());

                        dblSubTotal2 += Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Retailer mapped").ToString());
                        dblTotal2 += Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Retailer mapped").ToString());
                    }
                }////////////// Such types of calculations are there in 100's of switch cases.
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                 }
           break; /////////// there are 100's of cases in switch statement, if reduced to 15-20 cases 
         then runs without any exception. 
        }
    }
```

This is the exception which is generated on OnRowDataBound event.

[image]

Comment: It´s probably not the number of cases but a specific case that causes those problems. Having said this all we can do here is guessing about that missing case, that you didn´t post into the question. Btw.: `case "" { } break` seems pretty weird, I wonder if that even compiles.

Comment: `switch (Condition="")` does compile. however it performs a switch on a bool, not on the string. You probably want `switch(Condition) { case "": { ...; break; } }`.

Comment: Without your **actual** code it´s nearly impossible to help you. You should definitly provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can only guess if the compiler-errors mentioned before are related to your question or if your actual problem is within any of the cases you didn´t post.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have corrected the switch condition.

Comment: The `break` should probably be **within** every case-statement.

Comment: *and the whole OnRowDataBound event function is something around 13000 lines* - I have no words, but you have my sympathy

Comment: Use a binary chop strategy (remove half the cases, if problem occurs remove half remaining, if problem doesn't occur add half removed cases back, repeat) to find the case causing the problem and post it here into your question. Perhaps it calls gvReport_RowDataBound or something that, in turn, causes it to be called again (like a data bind?). You could also use the debugger to step and watch which case fires and why the code goes round and round and round the same methods until it crashes

Comment: A `StackOverflowException` usually occurs if you have some infinite recursion somewhere in your code. So somewhere your code is calling itself again and again, as Caius already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I would go is **dichotomy**, (Split your `switch cases` until you find the guilty one(s)). You have at least one (could be more) `switch case` that is triggering the same event (`OnRowDataBound`).
I know there are many cases but that's probably the most efficient way to get results. Once you find the suspect(s), you have to break (breakpoint) and do a step by step until you find the lines triggering the event and thus the recursion.
Also a good way to do it is to add a breakpoint at the entry of `gvReport_RowDataBound` then once you break, you do a few F5 to continue and build up a part of the `Call Stack`, then a look at the call stack window (Windows>Call Stack), a double click at each line of the call stack will bring you to the line triggering it in the code, and there you can see which case is triggering the recursion.